# PhpStorm language injections and deployment configuration

Tags: phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm for few months now and I have just noticed something really weird about language injections in the version 9.0.

Sometimes I have to declare that some strings in my PHP are Javascript instructions. When I do so and save my file (with auto-upload on), it looks like PhpStorm is doing a lot of remote checks, file moves and transfers, I dont really understand why... and I'm afraid that it may overwrite files that I didn't modifie. I'm working directly on a production server with other people, I know it's dangerous but we have no choice for the moment.

In the file transfer logs, I have something like that :

```
[18/09/2015 10:47] Automatic upload completed in less than a minute: 2 items deleted, 50 items moved, 4 files transferred (4 Kb/s)
```

Can someone help understand what is going on ?

Comment: 1) Enable **detailed** report (each file transfer will be logged) and not just summary 2) Most likely you have set to automatically upload your files and delete files that are no longer available locally. I strongly suggest you to disable such options **especially** since you are working with other people at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like PhpStorm is renaming all files that are opened in my edoior with the exact same name... weird... and uploads files that I have edited. I don't really understand why it does it only after language injections... I think that I will indeed upload files manually. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: *"It looks like PhpStorm is renaming all files that are opened in my edoior with the exact same name... weird"* That's sounds weird indeed. How did you discovered that (that is happens to all files with the same name)? What do you do to make that happen?

Comment: I discovered it by enabling detailed logs on file transfers (as you advise me).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do what I want, but didn't find the reason of theses uploads that PhpStorm does without asking anything...

The problem is that, until now, I didn't found a way to save files one by one. It looks like PhpStorm has only a "Save all" option that uploads every files changed since last save (if you ask for auto-upload). And in the case of a language injection PhpStorm seems to change a something in the opened files that forces it re-upload them all.

So I disabled auto-upload and bound a shortcut to "Upload to default server". This option uploads only your current file but it saves it before. So it's a kind of auto-upload but a little less agressive and it gives me the possibility to just save my files (with "save all") or to save only the current one and upload it instantly.

This is the way I used to work before using PhpStorm, I find it more convenient and less violent than this automatic upload process that Phpstorm uses.

If someones find something better I'm opened to any advice.

Comment: You can save current document only (instead of default Save All) but you will have to assign a custom shortcut for it yourself in `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`. The action called `Save Document` -- use a search field to quickly locate it. Keep in mind that autosave will still be kicking in in usual places without asking for confirmation (e.g. switching to another app (can be disabled); after saving Settings; before running script or switching to built-in Terminal etc -- usual stuff).

Comment: Thank you for the "Save document" option, I didn't search enough... I already disabled auto-save, it was a bit dangerous with auto-upload on